# Create transparent icon for iphone

Tags: iphone, icons, transparent, adobe-illustrator

I've read a lot and there are lots of sites that say that we "shouldn't" create an icon thats transparent, but I want to see how it looks.

Looking at apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)..

Note: You can prevent iOS from adding the shine to your application icon. To do this, you need to add the UIPrerenderedIcon key to your application’s Info.plist file (to learn about this file, see “The Information Property List” in iOS App Programming Guide).
The presence (or absence) of the added shine does not change the dimensions of your application icon.

I used Illustrator to create the icon.  I've made it the correct size.
When I look at the image in the simulator its black / transparent but I don't see my image.
Its not black its clear.  So I'm assuming that I have the info.plist file setup.

So if anyone has ideas how I need to save the png or if maybe I'm missing something some where.

[image]
[image]

Comment: There might be a possibility that Apple would reject an icon that doesn't match their usual style.

Comment: So, what is it that you're expecting to see?  Why do you think that something isn't right?

Comment: its clearly stated in the apple docs that you cannot create transparent icon for any application and if you will create it will appear to be black

Comment: Sorry I should have noted that the icon isn't completely transparent. The image has color. I was using black but with the black background I thought that it wasn't showing. So I changed it to red and still nothing.

Comment: @ iPhone Developer. Apples docs actually say that you can create an icon that's transparent, but there are only certain places where it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the icon transparent you can use the clearColor property, or you can reduce the alpha value. you can get a transparent view.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is 100% transparent guess what you see: the black background. But do you mean your image has varying alpha levels? I don't know about Illustrator, but in Photoshop you need to use File > Save for Web and Devices, not just File > Save, to get proper PNG translucency. Maybe similar since both are Adobe products.

But what is the point? Your icon might get rejected by Apple. You can achieve the same look on the home screen by pre-rendering your design on a black background (though I think they discourage a black background too). I guess it might look different when it appears in the app store on different backgrounds.

Comment: I do have something in the icon, besides the transparent back ground. :)

Answer (score 0):

For awhile Apple was inadvertently accepting apps with icons that has partial transparency (for cutouts and outlines).  However these icons did not show up properly in the App store, and Apple requested some (maybe all?) of these developers to change their icons to fully opaque.

One might want to do this for your own private apps (instead of white squares) only, but not for App store apps.